# split not working with attribute

Tags: javascript, jquery

So I was making a function to link to a page without showing the direction to the user and I had a problem and I don't know why is happening this.

here's my code:

```
function goTo(path) {
    var pageAttr = $(this).attr('goTo'),
        pageNExtension = pageAttr.split(' '),
        page = pageNExtension[0],
        extension = pageNExtension[1],
        pathName = path,
        locationToGo = pathName + page + extension;

    if (pathName == 'root') {
        window.location.href =  locationToGo; 
    } else if (pathName == 'sub') { 
        window.location.href =  locationToGo;
    } else { 
        window.location.href =  locationToGo;
    };
};
```

here is the element that calls the function:
    `<li goTo='home html' onclick='goTo('sub')'>Home</li>`

Comment: You should generally be using `data-*` attributes, not make up your own, as that would be invalid HTML.

Comment: What problem were you having?

Comment: Also, are you sure `this` is what you think it is, show us how you're calling that function and set the value of `this` while at the same time passing an argument!

Comment: @JayBlanchard the console shows me this: Uncaught TypeError: Object function linker(path) {
    var pageAttr = $(this).attr('linker'),
        pageNExtension = pageAttr.split(' '),
        page = pageNExtension[0],
        extension = pageNExtension[1],
        pathName = path,
    ...<omitted>...t'

Comment: And that's a clever if statement, there are three outcomes, but they are all the same ?

Comment: @adeneo `this` is working because I tried this before but was more simple than now.

Comment: @adeneo yeah there are 3 because now I was trying only if it was working

Comment: Then show us how the function is called, oh wait, you did, and you're not setting the value of `this` so it's not the element.

Comment: @adeneo: it's in the last line of the question `<li onclick=...`

Comment: @jwatts1980 - Just noticed, and that is the issue right there

Comment: the function is called by `li`mate

Comment: It is, and `this` will be the window inside that function, not the element.

Comment: @jwatts1980 let him talk, don't worry mate :) and thanks for passing by!

Comment: @Mr.Swaggalicious: adeneo has got it right. Your `this` is in the wrong context. Should be `onlcick="goTo(this, 'sub')"` and your function `goTo(el, path)` and in the function like `pageAttr = $(el)...`

Comment: You could also be a little fancy and do `onclick="goTo('sub').bind(this)"`, that way `this` would in fact have the right value inside the function and you don't have to change the function at all.

Comment: thanks @adeneo here you have a point! I will try that but I would like to keep it simple ^^

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An example

```
<input type="text" goTo="1 2 3" onclick="goto(this, 'path');">
<script>
    function goto(obj, path){
        var pageAttr = $(obj).attr('goTo'),
            pageNExtension = pageAttr.split(' ');
        console.log(pageNExtension);
    }
</script>
```

Output

[image]

Comment: thx but I would like to do it without putting `this`, is it posible?

Comment: then use jQuery selector

Answer (score 0):

Try using the data attribute.

Your HTML

```
<li data-goTo="home html" onclick="goTo('sub')">Home</li>
```

Your JS

```
var pageAttr = $(this).data('goTo');
```

The data attribute is more supported.

**More Reading:**

- [jQuery Data](http://api.jquery.com/data/)
- [The Data Attribute](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/HTML/Using_data_attributes)